# Can you get the volume of a webrtc audio stream without playing it?

Tags: javascript, audio, webrtc, mediastream

I have a bunch of webrtc streams represented in an angularjs view and I want to visualize which ones are over a certain volume threshold where I can then listen to those ones one at a time. Is this possible? Everything I find seems to require you to attach the stream to your audiocontext to calculate the volume. And this plays the stream. Can you calculate the volume without playing the stream? I have been playing with hark.js for volume threshold detection.

my stream is derived from a 3rd part rtc library but ultimately I have a bunch of webrtc streams and want to listen to one at a time while visualizing which ones are making noise. Most examples of this seem to have this logic on the broadcasters side.

The hark code pretty much does the following:

-start

```
    var audioContextType = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var audioContext = new audioContextType();
    var analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
    analyser.fftSize = 512;
    analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.1;
    var node = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    node.connect(analyser);//plays stream
```

-loop

```
    var fftBins = new Float32Array(analyser.fftSize);
    analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(fftBins);
    //check fftBins for volume data
```

-also I get the streams from an icelink, 3rd party webrtc library, object. The video collection in the view is created from a bunch of streams like so

```
    var remoteStream = fm.icelink.webrtc.linkExtensions.getRemoteStream(link);
    var videoObject = angular.element('<video></video>');
    videoObject.attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(remoteStream.getBackingStream()));
    videoObject.attr('autoplay', 'true');
    resolve(videoObject);
```

I am trying to overlay some visual indicators to show sound level on different video streams without playing them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to "play" a stream to hook it up to an `AudioContext`. Just `connect` to an [analyser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode), and omit `node.connect(audioCtx.destination)` to forgo default speaker output.

Comment: Can you create an analyser outside of the window.AudioContext? I am using hark which connects to an analyser but plays over the speakers at that point

Comment: @jumpdart Not sure what you mean. Analyser [wfm](https://jsfiddle.net/0s769z0d/) without speaker output.

Comment: The mic seems to be fine. Might be an issue with my rtc library. Taking the stream off of a third party webrtc object as a standard media stream but am having issues

Comment: Like I think because I have the streams bound to a bunch of video elements. I only wanted to play the audio to one stream at a time while visualizing the audio for all of them, but i think the fact that I have them attached to the video elements is screwing me up.

Comment: I had to clone the stream to analyse it.